# Delete an element from a collection

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm facing to a stupid problem. I have created a collection select which is creating elements into a join table "staffs_task" to reference an association between the model staff and task.
And now I would like two things: (1) a button delete this association (2) and a little bit of code for my model staffs_task to avoid duplication, so with the task_id and staff_id. And last info, task is a model built by ranch

my code:

(the collection in new_task)

```
<%= select_tag "staffs_task", options_from_collection_for_select(@staffs, 'id', 'name') , :multiple => true %>
```

(task_controller)

```
  skip_before_action :configure_sign_up_params
  before_action :set_ranch
  before_action :set_task, except: [:create]



  def create 
    @task = @ranch.tasks.create(task_params)
    @staffs = Staff.where(:id => params[:staffs_task])
    @task.staffs << @staffs
    if @task.save
      @task.update(done: false)
      @task.update(star: false)
      flash[:success] = "The task was created "
    else 
      flash[:success] = "The task was not created "
    end
    redirect_to @ranch
  end 


private

  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:content, :deadline, :row_order, :date, :assigned_to)
  end

  def set_ranch 
    @ranch = Ranch.find(params[:ranch_id])
  end 

  def set_task 
    @task = @ranch.tasks.find(params[:id])
  end
```

So if you have any idea about one of this two things, your help would be welcome 
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have the following many to many setup with a join model:

```
class Staff
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :tasks, through: :assignments
end

class Task
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :staff, through: :assignments
end

class Assignment
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :staff
end
```

Note that the [plural of **staff** is *staff*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/staff) - unless you are talking about the sticks carried by wizards.

ActiveRecord creates "magical" `_ids` setters for all `has_many` relationships. When used with a `has_many through:` relationship rails is smart enough to just remove the rows from the join table.

You can use this with the [collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) and collection_checkboxes methods:

```
<%= form_for([@task.ranch, @task]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:staff_ids, Staff.all, :id, :name, multiple: true) %>
<% end %>
```

You would then set your controller up like so:

```
def create 
  @task = @ranch.tasks.new(task_params) do |t|
    # this should really be done by setting default values
    # for the DB columns
    t.done = false
    t.star = false
  end

  if @task.save
    redirect_to @ranch, success:  "The task was created"
  else 
    render :new, error: "The task was not created"
  end
end 

private

def task_params
  params.require(:task)
    .permit(:content, :deadline, :row_order, :date, :assigned_to, staff_ids: [])
end
```

`staff_ids: []` will allow an array of scalar values. Also not that `.new` and `.create` are not the same thing! You where saving the record 4 times if it was valid so the user has to wait for 4 expensive write queries when one will do.